# How do I move multiple cards when making spider solitaire?

Tags: java

I am trying to make spider solitaire and have been stuck on being able to move multiple cards at once. My approach is to move all the cards into an arraylist while they are being moved and then add them onto the correct stack once the mouse is released. I'm not sure why this is not working, possibly an error in graphics?
Here is my code:

```
package spidersolitaire;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.applet.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Display extends javax.swing.JApplet implements ActionListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{
    private Deck deck;
    private Timer t= new Timer(1, this);
    ArrayList<Card> onTable[]= new ArrayList[10];   
    boolean isFaceUp[][] = new boolean[7][10];
    Card toBeDealt[][]= new Card[5][10]; //50 total cards
    private Position [][]cardCoordinates= new Position[10][50];
    private Card tempCard= null;
    int tempCardIndexA;
    int tempCardIndexB;
    private int tempX;
    private int tempY;
    int numberOfDeals=0;
    int numberOfDealsDisplay=5;
    ArrayList<Card> moveableStack= new ArrayList<Card>();
    boolean isMoveableStack= false;
    boolean isPlaced= false;


        public Display(){

            Object []values= {"EASY", "HARD"};
            int input= JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "CHOOSE DIFFICULTY", "DIFFICULTY", 0, 0, null, values, 0);
            deck= new Deck(input);
            deck.assignCards(onTable, toBeDealt, isFaceUp);
            int x=10;
            int y=10;
            for(int r=0; r<10; r++){
                x+=105;
                y=10;
                for(int c=0; c<50; c++){
                    y+=20;
                    cardCoordinates[r][c]= new Position(x,y);
                }
            }
            for(ArrayList<Card> e: onTable)System.out.println(e);
            addMouseMotionListener(this);
            addMouseListener(this);
        }

        public void init(){
            this.setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1270, 900)); //1270 900
            t.start();

        }

        public void paint(Graphics g){ 

            g.setColor(new Color(150,150,50));
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 1270, 900);            
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawImage(getImage(getDocumentBase(), "backofcard.jpg"), 1070, 700, this); //deal card graphics
            g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 30));
            g.drawString("Deals Left: " + numberOfDealsDisplay, 990, 820);
            int drawAtX=10;
            int drawAtY=10;
                for(int col=0; col<10; col++){ //displays all cards on table
                    drawAtX+=105;
                    drawAtY=10;
                    for(int row=0; row<onTable[col].size(); row++){ 
                    drawAtY+=20;
                        if(row<5){
                            if(isFaceUp[row][col])g.drawImage(getImage(getDocumentBase(), onTable[col].get(row).getImageName()), drawAtX, drawAtY, this);
                            else g.drawImage(getImage(getDocumentBase(),"backofcard.jpg"), drawAtX, drawAtY, this);
                        }
                        else g.drawImage(getImage(getDocumentBase(), onTable[col].get(row).getImageName()), drawAtX, drawAtY, this);

                    }
                }

                if(isMoveableStack){
                    //System.out.println(isMoveableStack);
                    int yx= tempY;
                    for(int s= 0; s<moveableStack.size(); s++){
                        g.drawImage(getImage(getDocumentBase(), moveableStack.get(s).getImageName()), tempX-20, yx, this);
                        yx+=20;
                    }
                    isMoveableStack=false;

                }

                try{g.drawImage(getImage(getDocumentBase(), tempCard.getImageName()), tempX-20, tempY-20, this);}//moving cards, catches exception thrown before tempCard is set
                    catch(NullPointerException e){

                    };


        }

        public void setMoveableStack(int Ax, int By){
            int cardsAdded=0;
            System.out.println(Ax + ", " + By);
            for(int b= By; b<onTable[Ax].size();b++){
                if(By==b)moveableStack.add(onTable[Ax].remove(By));
                if(onTable[Ax].get(b).getRank()+1==moveableStack.get(cardsAdded).getRank()&&onTable[Ax].get(b).getSuit()==onTable[Ax].get(b-1).getSuit()){
                    moveableStack.add(onTable[Ax].remove(By));
                    cardsAdded++;
                }
                else break;
                isMoveableStack=true;
            }
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if(e.getX()>1070&&e.getX()<1140&&e.getY()>700&&e.getY()<795){
                if(numberOfDeals<5){
                    System.out.println();
                    for(int i=0; i<onTable.length;i++){

                    onTable[i].add(toBeDealt[numberOfDeals][i]);
                    System.out.println(toBeDealt[numberOfDeals][i]);
                    }
                    }

                numberOfDeals++;
                if(numberOfDealsDisplay>0) numberOfDealsDisplay--;

                repaint();

                }
            }



        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {


        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {


        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            for(int a=0; a<10; a++){
                for(int l=0; l<onTable[a].size(); l++){
                    if(e.getX()>cardCoordinates[a][l].getCordX()&&e.getX()<cardCoordinates[a][l].getCordX()+71 //finds what card user clicks on based on Position cardCoordinates[][] and sets to tempCard
                            && e.getY()>cardCoordinates[a][l].getCordY()&&e.getY()<cardCoordinates[a][l].getCordY()+20){
                        if(l>6){
                            tempCard=onTable[a].remove(l);
                            setMoveableStack(a, l);

                        }
                        else if(l<7&&isFaceUp[l][a]){
                            tempCard=onTable[a].remove(l);
                            setMoveableStack(a, l);
                        }
                        tempX= cardCoordinates[a][l].getCordX();
                        tempY= cardCoordinates[a][l].getCordY();
                        tempCardIndexA=a; //the arraylist/stack
                        tempCardIndexB=l; //the index of the arraylist
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        @Override

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        for(int i=0; i<cardCoordinates.length; i++){
            if(e.getX()>cardCoordinates[i][0].getCordX()&&e.getX()<cardCoordinates[i][0].getCordX()+80&&(onTable[i].get(onTable[i].size()-1).getRank()==tempCard.getRank()+1||(onTable[i].size()==0))){
                    for(int c= 0; c<moveableStack.size(); c++){
                        onTable[i].add(moveableStack.remove(0));
                    }


                isMoveableStack=false;
                if(tempCardIndexB>1)
                    isFaceUp[tempCardIndexB-1]
                            [tempCardIndexA]=true;

            }
            else isPlaced=false;

        }
        if(!isPlaced){
            for(int c= 0; c<moveableStack.size(); c++){
                onTable[tempCardIndexA].add(moveableStack.remove(0));
            }
            isPlaced=true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

        tempX= e.getX();
        tempY=e.getY();
        repaint();

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
   }
```

and other classes if needed:

```
package spidersolitaire;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class Card  {
private int suit; //0 for spades, 1 for hearts
private int rank;
private String CARD_IMAGE_NAME;

public Card(int s, int r){
    rank=r;
    suit=s;
    setImage();

}

public int getSuit(){
    return suit;
}

public int getRank(){
    return rank;
}
public String getImageName(){
    return this.CARD_IMAGE_NAME;
}

public String toString(){
    if(suit==0){
        if(rank==11)return "Jack of Spades";
        if(rank==1)return "Ace of Spades";
        if(rank==12)return "Queen of Spades";
        if(rank==13)return "King of Spades";
        return rank + " of Spades";
    }
    if(suit==1){
        if(rank==11)return "Jack of Hearts";
        if(rank==1)return "Ace of Hearts";
        if(rank==12)return "Queen of Hearts";
        if(rank==13)return "King of Hearts";
        return rank + " of Hearts"; 
    }
    return "";
}


public void setImage(){
    if(suit==0){
        if(rank==1)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "spadesace.jpg";
        if(rank==2)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "spades2.png";
        if(rank==3)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "spades3.jpg";
        if(rank==4)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "spades4.jpg";
        if(rank==5)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "spades5.jpg";
        if(rank==6)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "spades6.jpg";
        if(rank==7)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "spades7.jpg";
        if(rank==8)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "spades8.jpg";
        if(rank==9)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "spades9.jpg";
        if(rank==10)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "spades10.png";
        if(rank==11)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "spadesj.jpg";
        if(rank==12)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "spadesq.jpg";
        if(rank==13)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "spadesk.jpg";
    }
if(suit==1){
        if(rank==1)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "heartsa.png";
        if(rank==2)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "hearts2.png";
        if(rank==3)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "hearts3.png";
        if(rank==4)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "hearts4.png";
        if(rank==5)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "hearts5.png";
        if(rank==6)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "hearts6.png";
        if(rank==7)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "hearts7.png";
        if(rank==8)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "hearts8.png";
        if(rank==9)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "hearts9.png";
        if(rank==10)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "hearts10.png";
        if(rank==11)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "heartsj.png";
        if(rank==12)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "heartsq.png";
        if(rank==13)CARD_IMAGE_NAME= "heartsk.png";
    }

}}
```

.

```
package spidersolitaire;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Deck {
private ArrayList<Card> cardList= new ArrayList<Card>(104);
private int difficulty;

    public Deck(int dif){ //makes a deck of 104 cards
        difficulty= dif;
        int temp=-1;
        if(dif==0)temp=3; //changes stopping point to switch suits if necessary
        if(dif==1)temp=1;
            for(int i=0; i <= temp; i++){
                for(int r=1; r<=13; r++){
                    cardList.add(new Card(0, r)); //adds 2 or 4 sets of black cards depending on difficulty selected
                }
            }
        if(temp==1){
            for(int i=0; i <= temp; i++){
                for(int r=1; r<=13; r++){
                    cardList.add(new Card(1, r)); //adds two sets of red cards if difficulty is hard
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<52; i++)cardList.add(cardList.get(i)); //copies the first half of the deck to make 104 total cards
        this.shuffle();

    }

    public void assignCards(ArrayList[] cards, Card [][] tbd, boolean [][] faceUp){ //cards on the table, cards to be dealt, and booleans if the card on table is face up
        for(int c= 0; c<cards.length; c++)cards[c]= new ArrayList<Card>();
        int num=0;
        for(int r=0; r<7; r++){
            for(int c=0; c<10; c++){
                faceUp[r][c]=false;
                if(num<54){
                    cards[c].add(cardList.get(num));}//puts cards in correct arraylist on the table
                    if(num>43)faceUp[r][c]=true; 
                    num++;
                }
            }

        num=54;
        for(int r=0; r<5; r++){
            for(int c=0; c<10; c++){
            if(num<104);
            tbd[r][c]=cardList.get(num);
            num++;
            }
        }


}


    public void shuffle(){
        int random= (int)(Math.random()*10)+3;
        for(int x= 0; x<=random; x++){ //shuffles a random number of times
        ArrayList<Card> halfOne= new ArrayList<Card>();
            ArrayList<Card> halfTwo= new ArrayList<Card>();
            int half=cardList.size()/2;
            for(int index=0; index<half;index++){
                halfOne.add(this.cardList.get(index));
            }
            for(int index=half; index<cardList.size(); index++){
                halfTwo.add(cardList.get(index));
            }
            ArrayList<Card> shuffled= new ArrayList<Card>();

            for(int i=0; i<half; i++){
                    shuffled.add(halfTwo.get(0));
                    shuffled.add(halfOne.get(0));
                    halfTwo.remove(0);
                    halfOne.remove(0);
                }
                if(cardList.size()%2==1)shuffled.add(halfTwo.get(0));
                this.cardList=shuffled;
        }
    }

    public void printDeck(){
        System.out.println(cardList);
    }

}
```

.

```
package spidersolitaire;

public class Position {
private int XPos;
private int YPos;


    public Position(int x, int y){
        XPos= x;
        YPos=y;
    }

    public int getCordX(){
        return XPos;
    }

    public int getCordY(){
        return YPos;
    }

}
```